# jquery validate giving an issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using following js scripts

```
<script src="JScript\jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="JScript\jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"   language="javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#userinfo").validate({
        rules: {
           NAME: {
                required: true
            }
        },
   messages: {
      NAME: {
      required: "Please Enter Password"
       }
         },
    onkeyup: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       alter('working');
       return false;
         }
       });
});
</script>
```

My html code is

```
<form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
<tr>
  <td>Name<span>*</span></</td>
  <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="NAME" class="autocomplete" value="" id="Name"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right"></td>
  <td><input type="button" class ="Submit_Button" value="Save" id="save">
<input type="button" class ="Submit_Button" value="Cancel" id="cancel">
   </td>
</tr>
```

Still I am not getting error message when Name is blank..also I have type="button" and not "submit".
I tried other options as well but somwhow this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "getting error when Name is blank", you just set it to required, what are you expecting ?

Comment: not getting error message, record is getting inserted in database. validation is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors (prior to the OP being edited)...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#userinfo").validate({
        rules: {
            NAME: {
                required: true
            }        // <-- missing }
        },                  
        messages: {
            NAME: {
                required: "Please Enter Password"
            }        // <-- missing }
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alter('working');   // <--  alert is spelled "alert", not "alter"
            return false;
        }
    });         // <-- missing });
});             // <-- missing });
</script>
```

---

**EDIT**

- You also have invalid HTML.  You cannot have a `<form>` element as a sibling of a `<tr>` element (a direct descendant `<table>`), among other malformed HTML you'll need to check.  [Only certain elements are allowed as *direct* descents of a `<table>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
- Your button for submitting the form needs to be a `type="submit"` so that it's automatically captured by the plugin.  `<input type="submit" class="Submit_Button" value="Save" id="save">`
- The slashes in your script paths are backwards.  Should be `JScript/jquery.js`
- Even after you edited your OP, your `alert()` is still misspelled.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/kxnRD/**

Comment: Thanks..sorry while pasting my code i did typo. No syntax error in actual code. Still its not working.

Comment: @SwapnilRanadive, you need to be more careful when posting a question so that you don't waste everyone's time and efforts.  See my edited answer.